# Send AJAX email by calling a function

Tags: javascript, ajax, jquery

Following is my js function from which i have been trying to send an email from my contact form, I used validation checks which are working fine but when the code goes to send the form then the process stops there and receives no responce from `$.ajax`. Strangely when i used the very same code on click event `$('#send_message').click(function(e){` it worked fine but not when i removed the click trigger listen and tried to do via calling a function then it didnot work kindly let me know what i did wrong so i can fix the issue of sending email by calling a function

```
 $.ajax({
                    type:"POST",
                    url:"email.php",
                    data: $("#contact").serialize(),
                    success:function(result){
                        //alert(response);
                        if(result == 'sent')
                        {

                             $('#send_message').removeAttr('disabled').attr('value', 'Send Info');

                            //and show the mail success div with fadeIn

                        }
                        else
                        {

                            //show the mail failed div


                        }
                     }

                });
```

Comment: show the code that calls this function

Comment: Independent of your problem (see answer below) I suggest to use jquery form validation http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Validation it has also the feature to submit the form with ajax.

Comment: @PhilippMehrwald validating forms with javascript is extremely dangerous - anybody can overwrite the js. Form validation should be done mainly from the server side and then as a `cosmetic` feature you may have some form of js validation. Otherwise the submitted information may be corrupted/invalid.

Comment: @tftd I **completely** agree with you. But as you say, for cosmetics it is easy to use and you "maybe" get rid of additional complex server side validation (I usually do) - of course people who deactivated JS will not get the same experience (honestly: I do not care).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to always return false. An ongoing ajax postback is canceled by a form submit.

So just remove the `else`.

jquery ajax is also supporting synchronous postbacks:

```
$.ajax({
   type:"POST",
   url:"send_email.php",
   data: $("#contact").serialize(),
   async: false,
   success:function(result){
```

**EDIT:** the first solution should also work but it is important to use the return in the form tag e.g. `<form method="POST" onsubmit="return somefunction();">`

Comment: Thanks alot sir `async: false,` it was the real problem and now its solved by adding this to my code.